# CSS-only: onHover, change style of all divs with class X?

Tags: html, css, sass, less

Say I have

```
<div class="vocal"> Item A </div>
<div class="consonant"> Item B </div>
<div class="consonant"> Item C </div>
<div class="consonant"> Item D </div>
<div class="vocal"> Item E </div>
<div class="num"> Item 1 </div>
<div class="num"> Item 2 </div>
<div class="num"> Item 3 </div>
```

onHover of `Item A`, I want all items that have a `vocal` class (`Item A` & `Item E`) to have a certain background color. The same for `item E`: On hovering `item E`, `item E` & `item A` should change background color.

And the same for the other consonants & numbers. Is something like this possible with *CSS only*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately this is not possible with pure CSS.

### However

It is possible to do this with javascript. You can do it like this:

Html:

```
<div class="vocal" onmouseover="show('vocal')" onmouseout="hide('vocal')"> Item A </div>
<div class="vocal" onmouseover="show('vocal')" onmouseout="hide('vocal')"> Item B </div>
etc...
```

Javascript:

```
function show(className) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
       elements.item(i).classList.add(className + "-hover");
    }
}
function hide(className) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
       elements.item(i).classList.remove(className + "-hover");
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.vocal {
    background: white;
}
.vocal-hover {
    background: red;
}
etc...
```

While not the cleanest solution, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, but if you want the elements with the "vocal" class to have a default background color, when you move the pointer over, change the color, then it would be this way

```css
.vocal{

  background:red;
  
}
.vocal:hover ~ .vocal, .vocal:hover{

  background:blue;

}
```

```html
<div class="vocal"> Item A </div>
<div class="consonant"> Item B </div>
<div class="consonant"> Item C </div>
<div class="consonant"> Item D </div>
<div class="vocal"> Item E </div>
<div class="num"> Item 1 </div>
<div class="num"> Item 2 </div>
<div class="num"> Item 3 </div>
```

```
.vocal:hover{ background:blue; }
```

Comment: OP also wants the other elements with the same class, not just the ones that are hovered over, to change the background color. This will only change the elements that are hovered over.

Comment: I  made an attempt, but it only works in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative (shorter) way of doing it with JS:

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="vocal" onmouseover="show()" onmouseout="hide()"> Item A </div>
<div class="vocal" onmouseover="show()" onmouseout="hide()"> Item B </div>
```

And here is the JS

```
let x = document.getElementsByClassName("vocal");

const show = () => {
  x[0].style.background = "red";
  x[1].style.background = "red";
}

const hide = () => {
  x[0].style.background = "none";
  x[1].style.background = "none";
}
```